# How to assign the value in a key to a constant name using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Here's my code

```
let currencies = ["US": "Dollar", "UK": "Pound", "JP": "Yen"]
```

Now, from here, I'd like assign the value for key "UK" to a constant named ukCurrency.

Comment: If you can assign to it it's not a constant.

Comment: I'll rephrase: Assign the value for key "UK" to a constant named ukCurrency.

Comment: You'd have to use some sort of compile-time expression.  Does Swift have a compile-time macro facility more sophisticated than C's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure that `"UK"` is there, use

```
let ukCurrency = currencies["UK"]
println(ukCurrency) // This prints Optional("Pound")
```

This would produce an optional value. On the other hand, if you know that `"UK"` key is definitely there, you could add an exclamation point after the expression to force unwrapping, like this:

```
let ukCurrency = currencies["UK"]!
println(ukCurrency) // This prints "Pound"
```

Comment: let ukCurrency = currencies["UK"]  Was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably to use the nil coalescing operator in conjunction with let and lookup:

```
let ukCurrency = currencies["UK"] ?? "UK Currency Not Defined"
```